# How to get rid of syntax error on token "public" in main class?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am getting a syntax error in my main class when I call the constructor from another class that I need for the main program to run. This program is focused on inheritance and the appropriate calling of constructors and arguments. This is the error message I get during compilation:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        Syntax error on token "public", record expected after this token

        at a6main.main(a6main.java:7)
```

This is the line of code that is causing the error:

```
PreferredCustomer c = new PreferredCustomer("Al", "222BurdSt", "2102223321", "46821",
"2000", true, "1000");
```

The rest of the code can be found below:

```
class person {

    String Name;
    String Address;
    String Telephone;

    person (String Name, String Address, String Telephone) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Address = Address;
        this.Telephone = Telephone;
    }
    
    String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    
    String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }
    
    String getTelephone() {
       return Telephone;
    }
    
    void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
    
    void setAddress(String Address) {
        this.Address = Address;
    }
    
    void setTelephone(String Telephone) {
        this.Telephone = Telephone;
    }
}

public class customer extends person {

    String number;
    boolean OnMailingList;

    //constructor and getters and setters

    customer (String Name, String Address, String Telephone, String number, boolean OnMailingList) {
        //inherit persons information
        super(Name, Address, Telephone);
        this.number = number;
        this.OnMailingList = OnMailingList;
    }
    
    String getnumber() {
        return number;
    }

    void setnumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    boolean OnMailingList () {
        return OnMailingList;
    }

    void setOnMailingList(boolean OnMailingList) {
        this.OnMailingList = OnMailingList;
    }
}

public class PreferredCustomer extends customer {

    private int purchase;
    double discount;

    /**public constructor so its accessible to main
     * else ifs for certain percentage of discounts
     * getters and setters for purchase and discount
     * super to inherit other features from other classes */
    public int getpurchase() {
        return purchase;
    }

    public double getdiscount () {
        return this.discount;
    }

    public void setPurchase(int purchase) {
        this.purchase = purchase;
    }

    public PreferredCustomer(String Name, String Address, String Telephone, String number, int pur, 
                            boolean OnMailingList, double Discount, PreferredCustomer preferredCustomer) {
        
        super(Name, Address, Telephone, number, OnMailingList);

        this.purchase = pur;
        preferredCustomer.discount = discount;

        if (this.purchase>= 2000) {
            this.discount = 10;
        } else if (this.purchase>= 1500) {
            this.discount = 7;
        } else if (this.purchase>= 1000) {
            this.discount = 6;
        } else if (this.purchase >= 500) {
            this.discount = 5;
        }
    }
}
    

public class a6main {
    
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        
    public PreferredCustomer() {

    }

    PreferredCustomer c = new PreferredCustomer("Al", "222BurdSt", "2102223321", "46821","2000", true, "1000");
   
        System.out.println("Name: " + c.getName());
        System.out.println("Address: " + c.getAddress());
        System.out.println("Telephone number: " + c.getTelephone());
        System.out.println("Customer ID: " + c.getnumber());
        System.out.println("Amount spent: " + c.getpurchase());
        System.out.println("On mailing list: " + c.OnMailingList());
        System.out.println("Discount: " + c.getdiscount());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is all your code in the same file?

Comment: @azurefrog Yes they are in the same folder

Comment: Well it doesn't know how to parse `public PreferredCustomer() {}` because that would be a constructor in the `PreferredCustomer` class. Instead it's randomly put in the `main()` method of your program in the `a6main` class. Simply delete the three lines, they don't do anything. It probably was a copy-paste mistake anyway?

Comment: @PetrJaneček Ok i did that, now the PreferredCustomer constructor in main is undefined...                                                   PreferredCustomer c = new PreferredCustomer("Al", "222BurdSt", "2102223321", "46821","2000", true, "1000");

Comment: @AlwinBaybayan Hi ,  your PreferredCustomer constructor takes 9 arguments.   You are calling this constructor using  new PreferredCustomer("Al", "222BurdSt", "2102223321", "46821","2000", true, "1000");

Therefore, either you go fix your public PreferredCustomer(xxxxx) constructor to take only 7 arguments, or you use this constructor and pass 9 values to it...

Also I see something weird in your public PreferredCustomer() constructor....Why are you passing , PreferredCustomer preferredCustomer) this to it? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several mistakes here. I've corrected them, and the program launches, providing the result:

> Name: Al
> Address: 222BurdSt
> Telephone number: 2102223321
> Customer ID: 46821
> Amount spent: 2000
> On mailing list: true
> Discount: 10.0

Remove PreferredCustomer constructor from the main method. It can't be a part of a
method, it is a part of a class. Then, the constructor for PreferredCustomer is *already present* in PreferredCustomer class.

Hopefully, your customer and PreferredCustomer classes are in separate files? If not, put them in separate files named customer.java and PreferredCustomer.java. In `PreferredCustomer` class constructor, remove `PreferredCustomer preferredCustomer` from arguments. It's redundant: why you need to pass one customer into another? Do customers have any relationships with each other? Now the number of arguments will match when you call the constructor (and don't use strings "2000", "1000" where should be integers):

```
PreferredCustomer c = new PreferredCustomer("Al", "222BurdSt", "2102223321", "46821",
2000, true, 1000);
```

Further in the PreferredCustomer constructor, use `this` instead of `preferredCustomer` here: `this.discount = Discount;` and print `Discount` with upper case, as in the signature of the constructor.

As a result, the code of the constructor should be:

```
public PreferredCustomer(String Name, String Address, String Telephone, String number, int pur, boolean OnMailingList, double Discount) {
    super(Name, Address, Telephone, number, OnMailingList);
    this.purchase = pur;
    this.discount = Discount;

    if (this.purchase>= 2000) {
        this.discount = 10;
    } else if (this.purchase>= 1500) {
        this.discount = 7;
    } else if (this.purchase>= 1000) {
        this.discount = 6;
    } else if (this.purchase >= 500) {
        this.discount = 5;
    }
}
```

The main method in a6main class:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    PreferredCustomer c = new PreferredCustomer("Al", "222BurdSt", "2102223321", "46821", 2000, true, 1000);

    System.out.println("Name: " + c.getName());
    System.out.println("Address: " + c.getAddress());
    System.out.println("Telephone number: " + c.getTelephone());
    System.out.println("Customer ID: " + c.getnumber());
    System.out.println("Amount spent: " + c.getpurchase());
    System.out.println("On mailing list: " + c.OnMailingList());
    System.out.println("Discount: " + c.getdiscount());
}
```

And take care of naming conventions, as other people pointed.